# Is there a way to separate dependency declarations into a file of it's own in node/express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, dependencies

I'm just learning node.js, express, etc -- and my code is a bit cluttered. What I'm trying to do is take all of my dependency declarations such as:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
etc, etc, etc
```

and put them in a separate module of their own, and then at the top of my main app.js, just do something like:

```
require('./modules/variables.js');
```

Is something like this even possible? I've researched quite a bit, but to be honest I'm not sure what to even look for. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Quite frankly, what you're trying to do really isn't recommended.  One advantage of the traditional style of listing the various dependent `require()` statements at the top of the module is to make your code more self documenting, to keep your code "modular" and to `require()` in only the modules you need in any given module.

Comment: Thank you. That does make sense.  The issue I'm running in to is that I'm creating some extra modules that I used based on certain events, and I have trouble getting the variables from my main app.js to carry over to the exampleModule.js -- unless I go in and var something = require('something');  at the top of each module I create, I get undefined errors.   I'm sure there's some simple way to pass them over, but I've not found it yet.  I do appreciate your time and the comment!    Should I edit my question to ask if it's "recommended", so that you can create an answer and I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do this, you can do the following early in your code:

```
global.mongoose = require('mongoose');
global.express = require('express');
global.path = require('path');
```

Some people would consider this heresy or very bad programming. Personally, I find it less ugly than having the same set of `require` lines at the top of many files.

For example, we use `log4js` in every single file, and the `log4js` variable is always the log4js module itself, so I think it's acceptable to have one line `global.log4js = require('log4js');` in a central place compared to having the line `var log4js = require('log4js');` in every single file.

You also wrote

> I have trouble getting the variables from my main app.js to carry over
>   to the exampleModule.js

The trick with `global` is *not* the way to accomplish that goal. If you need variables or data in different places, you should use `export` where you have the variable/data, and `require` where you need them.

For example, in `app.js`:

```
// db is the mongoose connection
module.exports = {
    db: db
};
```

And in `exampleModule.js`:

```
var appVars = require('./app.js');
// Now you can do something with appVars.db
```

(Note: this is not the best naming ever.)

Comment: Thank you. This is a great explanation. I feel like I understand what you're saying, and I'll go back and try to re-work my code to clean it up this way. I'll accept this answer since it's the most clear explanation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best way to do it, but I suppose you could create a module which imports all those dependencies, and sticks them into a context variable like this:

```
export dependencies = {
  mongoose : require('mongoose'),
  path : require('path'),
  ... etc
};
```

Then require that at the top of each page:

```
var dependencies = require('./[<path to your module>]/dependencies');
```

Then refer to those dependencies by deferrencing the from the dependencies object:

```
dependencies.mongoose.somefunction ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate file (lets say `variables.js`)

```
module.exports = {
    myFirstVar: 1234,
    mySecondVar: 'Hi there!'
};
```

Then you can require your variables using

```
var myVariables = require('path/variables.js')

console.log(myVariables.myFirstVar) //1234
```